# SKPhysicsBody inverted after Xcode 6.2 iOS 8.2 upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

EDIT: This is still broken in the 6.3/8.3 update. Anyone have a fix?

Prior to Xcode 6.2/iOS 8.2, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748034/spritekit-skphysicsbody-bodywithtexture-is-upside-down) question fixed my problem. Now my SKPhysicsBodies are upside down again after I reload the sprite, or create a new SKPhysicsBody from a previously "used" texture. This is a big problem for my game as it messes up my whole game play.

Here is where I load the textures in init:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKTextureAtlas *allTextures;
    - (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
    {
        self = [super initWithSize:size];
        if (self)
        {
            self.allTextures = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"AllTextures"];
            [SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:@[ self.allTextures ] withCompletionHandler:^{
                          NSLog(@"ATLASES LOADED");
            }];
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Here is where I create the Sprite and SKPhysicsBody:

// object is setup in @implementation as `SKSpriteNode *object;`

```
- (void)setupObject
{
    object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.allTextures textureNamed:@"Object01"]];
    object.position = CGPointMake(self.size.height / 2, object.size.width + 20);
    object.name = kObjectName;
    object.zPosition = 1;
    object.physicsBody = [self setupObjectPhysicsBody];
    [worldNode addChild:object];
}

- (SKPhysicsBody *)setupObjectPhysicsBody
{
    SKPhysicsBody *objectBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:object.texture size:object.size];
    objectBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    objectBody.dynamic = YES;
    objectBody.mass = 1.0;
    objectBody.restitution = 0.0;
    objectBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    objectBody.categoryBitMask = objectCategory;
    objectBody.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | obsticalCategory | waterCategory | blockCategory | otherCategory;
    objectBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory | obsticalCategory | otherCategory;
    objectBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    return objectBody;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe this is still not fixed in 8.3 b4! My games are all broken

Comment: I KNOW. It is just so infuriating. I have opened a case with Apple and heard  nothing!

Comment: This is still broken after 8.3/6.3 update.

Comment: Did you filled a radar?

Comment: @txaidw I did last week after going through the code support process to verify it was not me. No word yet.

Comment: Post the link here so we can support it!

Comment: i can't find, it is the correct id?

Comment: That is the correct number, although no movement yet from Apple. I am hoping 6.3.1 fixes it.

Comment: 6.4 beta 2 does not fix it.

Comment: I just finished a game and I'm waiting for this to work, any work around?

Comment: It probably won't, mine is completely in Swift and I have this problem :/

Comment: Oh darn. Thanks for that heads up.

Answer (score 2):

After all this time with this bug (since iOS 8.2?) I finally manage to get rid of the inverse physics body effect.

How did I fixed? I just replaced the sprite I was using with another for some other test, and it work without inverting the physics body. So I when to photoshop and made another version of the first sprite (the one with the problem), and it finally worked!!

So, I think this have to do with the complexity of the sprite, and maybe because it could not be finding a "closed shape" on the image, I don't know, but know it's working with the new sprite.

I hope you can at least continue your development now, and algo that Apple fixes that in the future!

Comment: So it worked, but then I kept updating my images and a few broke again, and then as I kept updating my images, some that were fixed, went back to being upside down. I am going to WWDC, so I am going to put this in front of an engineer.